# TypeScript - Partial<T> not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following throws:

```
Type '{ wheels: 4; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.
```

Here's the code:

```
interface Vehicle{
    wheels: number;
}

class Driver<T extends Vehicle>{
    car: Partial<T>;
    constructor(){
        this.car = {wheels: 4} 
        // Type '{ wheels: 4; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.
        // (property) Driver<T extends Vehicle>.car: Partial<T>
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As a workaround you can use: `this.car =  { wheels: 4 } as T;` But I also would like to to know why the error thrown...

Comment: It seems that it is considered as a legit error, although I wouldn't agree with it. Here it is the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19467) reported in TS repo, it also contains 3 other references to the same issue reported.

Answer (score -1):

Try this if it helps:

```
interface Vehicle {
    wheels: number
}
type DumpDriver = Partial<Vehicle>;
class Driver<T extends Vehicle> {
    car: DumpDriver;
    constructor(){
        this.car = { wheels: 4 };
    }
}
var doubleCross = new Driver();
console.log(doubleCross.car);

class WhichDriver<T extends Vehicle> {
    wheels: number;
    constructor(){
        this.wheels = 4;
    }
}
var whereIsTheBaggage = new WhichDriver();
console.log(whereIsTheBaggage.wheels);
```